# Store or print df.groupby without index

Tags: python, matrix, pandas-groupby

Using groupby I stucked at the moment to print my testdf without the indexes.

Is there any option to avoid indexes when storing testdf?

```
g = df2.groupby('genome')['accession'].apply(list).reset_index()

testdf = g.join(pd.get_dummies(g['accession'].apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0)).drop('accession', 1)

print testdf

             genome  VFG000475  VFG000477  VFG000478  VFG000670  VFG000926
0   GCA_000367685.2          0          1          1          0          0   
1   GCF_000026185.1          0          1          1          0          0   
2   GCF_000026985.1          0          0          0          0          0
```

Because to save it as .csv doing testdf.to_csv it works:

```
testdf.to_csv(outName, sep='\t', header=True, index=False)
```

And it is saved without indexes:

```
         genome VFG000475   VFG000477
GCA_000367685.2     0           1
GCF_000026185.1     0           1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you want to `print` your df without the index column.

To do so use:

```
print testdf.to_string(index=False)
```